# PDO upload pdf file to sql-database gives corrupted file

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to upload a pdf file to an sql server. I used to use SQL for this purpose and this worked for me without issues. However, to stay up to date I am switching to PDO. The issue I am now experiencing is that the file is corrupted when I try to download the data. The download script works when I use my old SQL upload script, so I do not think there is any issues with the download script. I am a complete rookie when it comes to PDO so I am not sure if there are any issues with my syntax.

```
$dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:host=server;dbname=database', 'user', 'pass');
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$ext = substr($fileName, strpos($fileName,'.'), strlen($fileName)-1);

if($_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0 && $ext == ".pdf")
    {
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
    $userid = //some user id is //

    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
        $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
        }

    $sqlfil = "UPDATE table SET filename = :ins_fileName, filesize = :ins_fileSize, filetype = :ins_fileType, filecontent = :ins_content WHERE id = :userid ";

    $statement = $dbConnection->prepare($sqlfil);
    $statement->bindValue(':ins_fileName', $fileName, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
    $statement->bindValue(':ins_fileSize', $fileSize, PDO::PARAM_INT, 20);
    $statement->bindValue(':ins_fileType', $fileType, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
    $statement->bindValue(':ins_content', $content, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $statement->bindValue(':userid', $aid, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
    $statement->execute();
```

**In summary,** the script only uploads 80% of the data to the LONGBLOB (as judged by what is in the sql-database) and thus the file is corrupted when it is downloaded. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Based on the suggestions from Marc B. **Working code:**

```
$dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:host=server;dbname=database', 'user', 'pass');
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$ext = substr($fileName, strpos($fileName,'.'), strlen($fileName)-1);

if($_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0 && $ext == ".pdf")
    {
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
    $userid = //some user id is //

    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    fclose($fp);

    $sqlfil = "UPDATE table SET filename = :ins_fileName, filesize = :ins_fileSize, filetype = :ins_fileType, filecontent = :ins_content WHERE id = :userid ";

    $statement = $dbConnection->prepare($sqlfil);
    $statement->bindParam(':ins_fileName', $fileName, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
    $statement->bindParam(':ins_fileSize', $fileSize, PDO::PARAM_INT, 20);
    $statement->bindParam(':ins_fileType', $fileType, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
    $statement->bindParam(':ins_content', $content, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $statement->bindParam(':userid', $aid, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
    $statement->execute();
```

Comment: you're doing it completely wrong: you're using prepared statements, there is **NO** need to use addslashes(), which is utterly **USELESS** to in preventing injection attack anyways. and you simply assuming that the upload has succeeded. checking for a non-zero size is **NOT** success. there's a `['error']` parameter in $_FILES for a reason. since you're manually adding slashes, **YOU** are the one corrupting the file by adding junk characters that are not present in the original and completely unecessary

Comment: Absolutely with Marc B here. `addslashes` is a sure sign this is [cargo-cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Take some time to read up on current PHP best practices in a guide like [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/). Magic quotes don't even exist in newer versions of PHP, so that code to deal with it is completely useless.

Comment: ...depends on the cargo I guess. See y'all on Pier 4.

Comment: Hehe. Wow, a lot of anger, Marc B...Appreciate the help though with dumping my excess cargo. Removed the addslashes and get_magic_quotes and that did the trick! In addition, I changed bindValues to bindParam. Working code has been posted

Comment: May I suggest that once you the:`setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);`, which is sensible  with 'mysql' then you only use the '?' as a placeholder in your queries. i.e. do not use names. The 'mysqli' driver does not know about `placeholder names` so you need to supply the parameters in the correct order.